# Send only if key was pressed alone

Tags: autohotkey

I'd like to remap my windows key to something else, but also I'd like to keep all windows key based shortcut.

In pseudo code it would be something like this:

`when LWin Down 
   until LWin Up 
     if not LWin down 
        abort
     else
        execute command`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Release the left windows key within 0,3 seconds after pressing it, to do something else (e.g. to send a):

```
~LWin::
KeyWait, LWin
return

~LWin Up::
Send {LWin Up}
If (A_PriorHotKey = "~LWin" AND A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 300)
    Send, a
; else  ; another action after long press (not recommendet)
    ; Send, b
return
```

**EDIT:**

Try also this:

```
LWin up::
If (A_PriorKey = "LWin")
    Send a
return

; In this case its necessary to define a custom combination by using "&" or "<#" 
; to avoid that LWin loses its original function as a modifier key:

<#d:: Send #d  ; <# means LWin
```

Comment: What is the `d` in the second version? `<#d::` What is `d`?

Comment: "<#d" is the native key combination "LWin+d" to toggle minimize all windows.

Comment: Ok I get it now.